# Pip cannot clone from https anymore - error 128

Tags: git, pip, gitea

I have had a project working with the standard https cloning syntax for a while, and just this afternoon it was working fine. Now, I get `error code 128` every time I try to clone:

```
Obtaining myproject from git+git://myurl/myuser/myproject.git@master#egg=myproject (from -r requirements.txt (line 28))
  ...
  fatal: unable to connect to myurl:
  myurl[0: x.y.z.q]: errno=Invalid argument

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q git://myurl/myuser/myproject.git Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have confirmed I am able to manually clone using

`git clone -q https://myurl/myuser/myproject.git`

As well as through SSH.

I am hosting my repositories on gitea, and I haven't found any errors related to this. This is very strange.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong? I even deleted my virtualenv folder and re-instantiated it with no luck, as well as restart my gitea server.

Answer (score 9):

See the [pip install doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git). If you want to use the `https` protocol then the syntax is:

`git+https://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject`

But from your question it looks like you are using the `git` protocol instead (`git+git://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject`). So this is a different protocol.

Comment: see the same docs, which also lists `git://git.example.com/MyProject.git@master#egg=MyProject`, which is what is posted in the question

Answer (score 6):

### tl;dr

I had a very similar error, which ended up being missing ca-certs for pulling HTTPS urls.  The fix was to:

```
apt-get install -y --reinstall ca-certificates
```

### Details

After digging a little deeper into the pip output, the underlying `git clone -q` was erroring out like so:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/blah/blah.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code in the file.

The original code is:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/snkas/exputilpy.git@v1.6 | | exit 1
pip install git+https://github.com/snkas/networkload.git@v1.3 | | exit 1
```

Change to:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/snkas/exputilpy.git@v1.6 | | exit 1
pip install git+git://github.com/snkas/networkload.git@v1.3 | | exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem
turns out I seated proxy for git and forgot to open the proxy app
you can check your git proxy with this

```
 git config --global https.proxy
```

and you can remove it with this

```
 git config --global https.proxy ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error and only add public key of ssh in my profile settings -> keys ssh and ready!

> Note: I installed the repo with this format for python project

```
pipenv install -e git+ssh://git.example.com/MyProject.git@master#egg=MyProject
```